# Excel Formula with multiple if condition

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel template that is used to conduct the assessment. I have below formula which I use to calculate the assessment scores.

=If(J2="","",If(J2=H2,I2,M2))

If the user skips the question, it will update blank, if the user selects the correct answer, it will update the score mentioned in column "H2". If the user selects an incorrect answer, It will update the negative score mentioned in "M2".

Now, I want to add an additional feature. the formula should also check if the given answer is partially correct and give the 0.5 marks.
I have mentioned the partial correct answer in column "N2". Please assist as to who to update the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest if statements. If I understoody you correctly, try

```
=If(J2="","",If(J2=N2,0.5,If(J2=H2,I2,M2)))
```